# jquery mobile 1.3 bugs in setting default value of selector?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

From this link, [http://jsfiddle.net/hRqZP/1/]1, I can able to set the default value of the radio input and selector, however, if i change it to jQuery Mobile 1.3, problems seem happened. The living place is not 789 instead it is 123. And the gender is not correct too. If the version of jQuery Mobile changes to 1.2, everything goes right. Is there any problems on 1.3 on these issue?